# HTML5 FileApi + FileReader - Feed <object> with SWF

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I want to use the HTML5 FileApi to read a SWF to an `OBJECT` (or `EMBED`, if it's better to do?).

My current code crashes on Chrome/Iron (the only *stable* browser which also supports the xmlhttprequest v2 FormData). I got it to read image data into a on-the-fly created IMG. But the object one crashes the current tab in the browser.

```
else if (file.type == "application/x-shockwave-flash") {
    var show = document.createElement("object");
    show.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash"
    show.style.width = "100%";
    show.style.height = "100%";
    show.id = "thumb";
    document.getElementById("thumbnails").appendChild(show);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (aImg) { 
        return function (e) { aImg.data = e.target.result; }; 
    })(show);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Do I really read to the `object.data` part? How is it done right? Anybody know? Or is this incomplete and I have to wait for better implementation?

Comment: Note that the 'data' attribute on the show object isn't relevant.  What you need is a <param> child node with name="movie" and value="yourdata".  See http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

Answer (score 2):

A few things I'd recommend trying (in order of increasing complexity):

- base64 encode the data with [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa) and set it using a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme),
- instead of creating the object using `createElement`, construct the `<object>` tag with all attributes as an HTML string (including the base64 advice above), then inject it into a DOM element with `innerHTML`,
- create a reflector web service where you POST the swf content, it gives you a URL, then pass the URL off to the object,
- similar to the previous, create a reflector web service where you POST the swf content, targeting a full-screen IFRAM as the target, have the service spits back an HTML doc including an `<object>` pointing back to the server.

The later of these options is more intense, and requires round-trips from the server that you'd probably want to avoid - just some more options you might want to consider.

ActionScript 3 has a [`Loader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html) which may be useful as well.  I don't know if it supports `data:` URI's, but if it does, you could write a boot loader SWF which runs the contents of the local swf file directly.

Comment: For the first suggestion, doing what I do above already gives back a `data:` URI. At least that is what is in the `<img src>` attribute after I assign the FileReader to give it's results to the src. The second suggestion seems like it could result in the same error, but maybe it somehow circumvents that one, I will try. The third and last one would work great I think. The site is an image and swf upload service. So I would change my code to instantly upload everything and give it tokens :). Then I can do this suggestion.

Comment: The important part about option #1 is the base64 encoding.  The SWF file is binary data, which may not go over well when crossing from JavaScript to DOM to plugin.  So, I recommend running e.target.result through btoa(), then create a string like "data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64," + btoa(e.target.result), and add a <param name="movie"> to the <object> with its value set using setAttribute("value", dataURI).  Having said all that, you're probably still better off with a reflector service.

Comment: I'll have to check what readAsDataURL(file); actually returns... If it's already base64 or not.. Research is due.. BTW: I could also try an OBJECT URL. how is that?

Comment: @jimbojw. Need some help on this post about fileapi... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456216/clarification-required-on-javascript-in-html5-fileapi-for-image-preview